# How to write a "generic wrapper class"? java

Tags: java, eclipse, class, methods, wrapper

This is what we have to do :

For your Queue class, you are to write it as a generic wrapper class around Java's LinkedList class

I know what the methods would be, I'm just wondering how to do the title, for example;

public class Queue ?????????? LinkedList(){}

What goes there?

Comment: Another name for a Queue is a [Stack](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/stack-unbound.html).

Comment: The homework is given to you so that you could learn something on your own. If you could not mange, at least try

Comment: Definitely NOT `public class Queue extends LinkedList`---or anything else involving `LinkedList` before the opening brace.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You need to be a bit careful with that. For some people (I don't know if it's most), a queue implies first-in-first-out, while stack implies last-in-first-out.

Comment: @yshavit Very true (and sometimes important) distinction.

Comment: @Sage I did try on my own and everything I could think of got errors, so I came here. Whats your problem?

Comment: @user3018822 People on SO tend to be pretty unreceptive to "please give me the answer to my homework" type questions. If you tried on your own and got errors, you should post what you tried and ask specific questions about those errors.

Comment: `Whats your problem?` My problem! I am just offering you a good advice. Your writing style of the question doesn't tell us that you did even search for any of the terms you have used in your question

Comment: @yshavit I might be wrong, but aren't FIFO and LIFO literally what define a Queue and a Stack, respectively? This is the first time I've ever heard of someone who considers them to be the same. (Also, yes, I know this was almost ten years ago).

Comment: @Nyde That's how I've always heard them defined, too. Wikipedia agrees with us, though I could have sworn that at the time it had some hedged language like "queues are _usually_ FIFO" (I don't feel like going back and checking the history ;) ).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a class `A`. You want to make a wrapper, `B` for it.

```
public class B {
    // Wrapped instance.
    private A wrapped;

    public B() {
        wrapped = new A();
    }
}
```

If `A` is generic, and you want `B` to be a generic wrapper, you just need to add the generic declaration.

```
public class B<T> {
    // Wrapped instance.
    private A<T> wrapped;

    public B() {
        wrapped = new A<T>();
    }

    // The remaining methods should delegate to A.
}
```

Now, you just need to figure out what is `A` and what is `B`, for your particular case.

Answer (score 1):

The hint from the assignment is **generic**.  What this means is it should work nicely as a container for any object.  You can do this with something like the following:

```
public class MyQueue<T> { 
    List queueImpl;
    MyQueue() { 
       queueImpl = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

}
```

and using it is as simple as:

```
MyQueue<String> toyQueue = new MyQueue<>();
```

OR

```
MyQueue<Integer> toyQueue = new MyQueue<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Java's [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) class IS a Queue!

It literally implements the [java.util.Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface

Comment: But it is not a generic wrapper around `LinkedList`, which is the *assignment* and not a real-world problem.